# How can I make chnages to a MERN app after deploying it to Heroku?

Tags: heroku, mern

I have created a MERN app and deployed it to Heroku. I now want to add some new features to my project. So, I added some new routes (/search) in the backend routes folder. But every time, I try the new route I get a 404 error. My NODE_ENV in the .env file and in my system is set to development. I have also added a proxy in the react package.json. Not sure what else I can do here. Any help will be appreciated.

[routes file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TN8e.png)

[backend package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsBTe.png)

[REACT package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qh0AY.png)

Comment: Are you trying to edit the files directly on Heroku? You can't do that. The normal workflow is to run a local development environment, make changes there, and when you're happy with them, redeploy to Heroku.

Comment: No, I am trying to make changes on my local machine

Comment: So what does this have to do with Heroku? How are you running your development server? Are you looking for hot reloading?

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Thanks for your input. To clarify, the app is deployed on heroku. I was trying to add some additional features (on my local machine) and then pushing to my GitHub repo (which is connected to heroku). I was able to fix the issue. The order of my routes in the backend folder was incorrect.

Comment: If you're ever looking for an alternative place to deploy MERN stack, there's a nice tutorial here for deploying on Render: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l134cBAJCuc